# is it ok to run high CPU performance needing software all the time?

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance

I have acre aspire laptop with Intel core i3-370M prossesor with 3.6 gb ram. I want to use IntelJ software for developing in java on this laptop.  When I ran this software it run little bit slowly but it at least runs.  I am fine with that speed but My laptop's fan start making noise and system monitor show this result:-

[image]

Will it be problem to my laptop if I continue to ue this software like this ?? I had to use this laptop for two more years until I graduate my diploma in IT.

here is more information about hardware:-

```
$ lscpu 
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 37
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU       M 370  @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              5
CPU MHz:               933.000
CPU max MHz:           2399.0000
CPU min MHz:           933.0000
BogoMIPS:              4788.00
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Using Linux Mint XFCE 18.2

Comment: Provided your system meets or exceed the specifications required to run IntelJ your system should be able to run it.  It sounds like that while your system can runt he program it does not meet the minimum specifications to run the program (hence the reason your laptop is CPU is extremely high).  The it normal for a heatsink to be louder when a CPU is under extreme loads like you are putting your CPU under (you are basically stress testing it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is ok to use the CPU at 100% all the time. They are designed for this. It will not hurt te CPU.

On a laptop it will be loud though and the fan cooling the system might wear out faster and it on battery the battery will empty faster. So in a few years consider replacing the CPU fan.